# Difference Between Spring Tool Suite and Groovy/Grails Tool Suite

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

I know that Spring Tool Suite is optimized for Spring development and Groovy/Grails is optimized for Groovy/Grails development. Is there any practical reason why a Groovy/Grails developer would want to use the Spring Tool Suite for Groovy Grails applications even though the developer will not be developing any Spring applications?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with Groovy and Grails only, I would recommend to download and use GGTS. If you want to work with Spring, I would recommend to use STS. If you want to work with both from within the same IDE, I would recommend to start with the STS distribution and install the Groovy-Grails parts into it from the dashboard. That way you get the features of both.

Answer (score 0):

STS and GGTS are both based on Eclipse and extend it with plugins. You can use STS or even a bare-bones Eclipse install, but since it has no Grails support by default you'd have to install that yourself. That's easy enough to do, but having it all preconfigured in GGTS saves you the hassle of doing that yourself.

Likewise, there are some plugins installed in STS that aren't preinstalled in GGTS, but those are also freely available, so you could install any of those that you want.